# What have I changed during a manual git merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I am in the middle of a big manual git merge, the code is not compiling, and I'm trying to figure out what I've done wrong. I think I can find out the difference between the working tree and my current branch with

```
git diff -C HEAD
```

and the difference between the working tree and the branch I'm trying to merge in with

```
git diff -C [name of other branch]
```

but that mixes in what I've just changed when fixing up the merge attempted by git, with the existing changes.

I want to separate out these three types of changes, so that I can clearly see what has changed and what might have introduced a compilation error.

Unfortunately I've also staged merge conflict resolutions using `git add`, so it's not as simple as just diffing between the working tree and the index to see what I've changed.

Comment: `git diff --cc` might help you.  It shows only "interesting" diffs, i.e. diffs with more than two different versions among the parents and the merge base, or diffs where not simply one of the two available versions was picked.  It leaves out trivially merged files, but still shows files that were automatically merged by git.